# Python - Count consecutive frequencies by group

Tags: python, pandas, sequence, frequency, python-itertools

I have a sequence of e-mails ordered by timestamp and user_id.

I want to investigate how often email i was followed by email j. I'm going to display these frequencies across users in a heat map to show the most common path.

```
a = """timestamp,email,subject
2016-07-01 10:17:00,a@gmail.com,subject2
2016-07-01 02:01:02,a@gmail.com,welcome
2016-07-01 14:45:04,a@gmail.com,subject3
2016-07-01 08:14:02,a@gmail.com,subject1
2016-07-01 16:26:35,a@gmail.com,subject4
2016-07-01 10:17:00,b@gmail.com,subject1
2016-07-01 02:01:02,b@gmail.com,welcome
2016-07-01 14:45:04,b@gmail.com,subject3
2016-07-01 08:14:02,b@gmail.com,subject2
2016-07-01 16:26:35,b@gmail.com,subject4
2016-07-01 18:00:00,c@gmail.com,welcome
2016-07-01 19:00:02,c@gmail.com,subject1
2016-07-01 20:00:04,c@gmail.com,subject3
2016-07-01 21:14:02,c@gmail.com,subject4
2016-07-01 21:26:35,c@gmail.com,subject2
"""

import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.parsers import StringIO
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(a), parse_dates=['timestamp'])
df1=df1.sort_values(['email','timestamp'])
```

sorted df1:

```
        timestamp        email   subject
 1  2016-07-01 02:01:02  a@gmail.com   welcome
 3  2016-07-01 08:14:02  a@gmail.com  subject1
 0  2016-07-01 10:17:00  a@gmail.com  subject2
 2  2016-07-01 14:45:04  a@gmail.com  subject3
 4  2016-07-01 16:26:35  a@gmail.com  subject4
 6  2016-07-01 02:01:02  b@gmail.com   welcome
 8  2016-07-01 08:14:02  b@gmail.com  subject2
 5  2016-07-01 10:17:00  b@gmail.com  subject1
 7  2016-07-01 14:45:04  b@gmail.com  subject3
 9  2016-07-01 16:26:35  b@gmail.com  subject4
 10 2016-07-01 18:00:00  c@gmail.com   welcome
 11 2016-07-01 19:00:02  c@gmail.com  subject1
 12 2016-07-01 20:00:04  c@gmail.com  subject3
 13 2016-07-01 21:14:02  c@gmail.com  subject4
 14 2016-07-01 21:26:35  c@gmail.com  subject2
```

The output should look like this

```
          welcome   subject1    subject2    subject3    subject4
welcome      0              
subject1     2         0                    
subject2     1         1          0     
subject3     0         2          1           0 
subject4     0         0          0           3             0
```

In other words, there were 2 occurrences where subject1 followed after a welcome email. There was 1 occurrence where subject 2 followed after a welcome message, etc.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: can you explain your output? it looks like subject4 and welcome should have 1 not 0

Comment: Edited the table. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two-liner (which you can compress to a one-liner):

```
df1['next_subject'] = df1.groupby('email')['subject'].shift(-1)
res = pd.crosstab(df1['next_subject'], df1['subject'])
print(res)

# subject       subject1  subject2  subject3  subject4  welcome
# next_subject                                                 
# subject1             0         1         0         0        2
# subject2             1         0         0         1        1
# subject3             2         1         0         0        0
# subject4             0         0         3         0        0
```

You can massage this a little bit to get it in the exact form you quote in the OP:

```
subjects = ['welcome'] + ['subject{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 5)]
res = res.loc[subjects, subjects].fillna(0).astype(int)
print(res)

# subject       welcome  subject1  subject2  subject3  subject4
# next_subject                                                 
# welcome             0         0         0         0         0
# subject1            2         0         1         0         0
# subject2            1         1         0         0         1
# subject3            0         2         1         0         0
# subject4            0         0         0         3         0
```